# Does this span contain this vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Gilt $\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\end{pmatrix}\in L\left(\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-2\\-4\end{pmatrix}\right)$?

Does the span L contain the vector (2,-1)

I tried to set up a Gaussian Equation System. from the following equation
 (2,-1)=a1*(1,2)+a2*(-2,-4)+a3*(0,0)

```
1:  1  -2  2
2:  2  -4 -1
_____________
```

according to that the vector should not be in the span?
is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your result is correct...though I cannot understand what system did you reduce by Gauss...??

Comment: I set up the following system
(2,-1)=a1*(1,2)+a2*(-2,-4)+a3*(0,0)

Comment: That's what I thought one would do, @user2147674, but then I get the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}a_1&-2a_2&2\\2a_1&-4a_2&-1\end{pmatrix}$$Note that the zero vector has no effect whatsoever in the span...

Comment: Sorry I mistyped, now It should be right. So if the vector war in the span, the system should be reducable to  0 0 0 0?

Comment: Well, now it is more comprehensible...but very misleading: the first column to the left seems to be just a way to *number* the rows, right? And do yourself a favour and do *not* write down that zeros column: better, just remark the zero vector **never** apports anything to any span so just omit it.

Comment: Exactly the "1 :" and "2 :" number the rows

Comment: Yes...at the first sight I didn't see that, and since the numbers $\;1,2\;$ appear in all the vectors (but the zero one) I just couldn't understand. I don't think you need to number the rows or, at least, *specify* this if you feel like doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es ist nicht gilt...just observe that the third vector in $\;L\;$ is a scalar multiple of the first one, and since the zero vector apports nothing, you have that that

$$\text{Span}\,L=\text{Span}\,\left\{\;\binom12\;\right\}\not\ni\binom2{\!\!-1}$$

Comment: Ah I see, did I approach the problem the right way with the gaussian equation?
If the vector was in the span, the gaussian equation could be reduced to 0 0 0 ?

Comment: See my comments below your question.